# Cannot find server explorer in Visual Studio 2012 express for web

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. I have downloaded MySQL Community server. When I try to connect to a database in VS by creating a new SQL server data item, I am unable to find "Server Explorer" in the view...

Comment: Must you use VS 2012? Why not 2015 ?

Answer (score 0):

The Servers node and its children are not available in some editions of Visual Studio. - quoted from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk(v=vs.110).ASPx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't go to View in the top menu and select Server Explorer from there?

Or Ctrl W, S